# How to select classes from a GeoTIFF world map and compute the area by regions defined in a shapefile

Tags: python, gdal, raster-calculator, zonal-statistics, rasterstats

I have two files:

- `fileLUse.tif` defines land cover classes in GeoTiff format (from https://www.esa-landcover-cci.org/?q=node/164)
- `fileRegions.shp` defines administrative borders and it is a shapefile (from https://gadm.org)

Both files are EPSG 4326, that if I understood it well it is WTS84 datum with coordinates system (no projected) and cover the whole World.

I need to select the land use classes from `fileLUse` whose value is in a certain range ([40-130]) and compute the area and area ratio of this aggregate for each region in `fileRegions`.
My "output" would then be a CSV with region name (from fileRegions), total area, share of aggregate land use.

My main problem is that the files are not projected, so I don't really know how to give them a unit, as all "equal area" projections I saw are specific for a certain area of the World.

Which approach should I take ? I could use QGIS, GRASS, R, Python... (I'm on Linux)

**[EDIT]**

What I have done so far:

- Computed 0/1 binary data of Land Covers in the interested range:

```
gdal_calc.py -A fileLUse.tif --outfile=fileNatVegAreas.tif --calc="logical_and(A>=40,A<=140)"
```

- I used [rasterstats](https://github.com/perrygeo/python-rasterstats) to get the mean/count of each "polygon"

```py
from rasterstats import zonal_stats
stats = zonal_stats("fileRegions.shp", "fileNatVegAreas.tif")
```

What I am left with:

- `stats` is a vector of dictionaries with the various stats, e.g.

```py
>>> stats[0]
{'min': 0.0, 'max': 1.0, 'mean': 0.5842002754571467, 'count': 739861}
```

***How do I link back my stats to the field "RegionName" in my shapefile, and possibly export everything as a CSV ?***

Answer (score 0):

At the end I done like this:

1. Computed the 0/1 Indicator Variable of the range

```
gdal_calc.py -A fileLUse.tif --outfile=natVegIndicator2019.tif --calc="logical_and(A>=40,A<=140)"
```

For some reason this created a 8GB map out of a 300MB original tif map.

2. Used the following simple Python script

```py
vectorBoundariesFile = "gadm36_1.shp"
rasterDataFile       = "natVegIndicator2019.tif"

sqKmPerCell          = (300*300)/(1000*1000)

from rasterstats import zonal_stats
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

stats   = zonal_stats(vectorBoundariesFile, rasterDataFile, stats=['mean', 'count','sum'])
regdf   = gpd.read_file(vectorBoundariesFile)

countCells  = pd.Series([i['count'] for i in stats])
sqKm        = countCells * sqKmPerCell  

means   = pd.Series([i['mean'] for i in stats])
sums    = pd.Series([i['sum'] for i in stats])


data    = [regdf['GID_0'], regdf['NAME_0'],regdf['GID_1'], regdf['NAME_1'],means,sqKm,countCells,sums]
headers = ["GID_0", "NAME_0","GID_1", "NAME_1","natVegRatio","SqKm","countAllCells","countForCell"]
out     = pd. concat(data, axis=1, keys=headers)

out.to_csv("vegIndex2019.csv")
```

An other (and perhaps better) approach is to just use the step #2 passing the parameter `categorical=True` to the `zonal_stats` function call (see the [rasterstat user manual](https://pythonhosted.org/rasterstats/manual.html#raster-data-sources)) and then compute the ratio of the desired range ex-post from the dataframe in Python.

Note that the final `SqKm` could be biased and different than official country-level statistics.. I learn that even just "measuring an area" on a large part of the Earth is not a trivial task. However, using the counts of cells to obtain the *ratio* of different land classes should be an unbiased method.

Comment: It's probably big because of the data type.  Try adding --type=Byte or limiting the extent of the output,  or both.